# Ignore line breaks and spaces after the >(html end tag) in the java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regular expression for the string

```
<h1><a href="/index.html"><img src="images/images.jpg" width="960" height="64" alt="[some string]" /></a></h1>
```

and it must be converted to

The alt of a is [some string]

I have used the following regular expression

```
\Q<h1><a href="/index.html"><img src="images/images.jpg" width="960" height="64" alt="\E(.*?)\Q" /></a></h1>\E
```

but when I get input like

```
<h1>
 <a href="/index.html">
   <img src="images/images.jpg" width="960" height="64" alt="[some string]" />
 </a>
</h1>
```

This regular expression does not works since it has line breaks and spaces after >

How to ignore the spaces and line breaks after the > in the above regular expression.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should use an html Parser. No regex.

Comment: [You cannot parse html with regex, because html is to complex for regex to be parsed in every condition, for example, tags can have multiple orders.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)